# Preserve line breaks in BizTalk outbound custom header

Tags: soap, biztalk, saml, biztalk-2013

I am receiving a message with SAML security ticket in the header.
This ticket must be sent in outgoing call without any changes.
Within a BizTalk orchestration I set this as an outbound custom header to the message I am sending.
The security ticket received contains tags that are separated with line breaks (CR+LN) as this:

```
<SignedInfo>
<OtherTag/>
<SomeTag>ABC</SomeTag>
</SignedInfo>
```

I am setting the outbound headers with this line breaks included:

```
MessageOut(WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders) = < string with header >
```

The problem is when the WCF-Custom adapter assembles the complete SOAP request with header and body, these line breaks between the tags are removed:

```
<SignedInfo><OtherTag/><SomeTag>ABC</SomeTag></SignedInfo>
```

This causes the ticket to be unvalid and rejected.

Is there any ideas of how to preserve these line breaks?

Comment: Are you sure the ticket needs to go in the header? You can try adjusting party settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configuring-fallback-charset-and-separator-properties-x12 . This article talks about an SSOTicket field.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/single-sign-on-support-for-the-soap-adapter . Is this soap with WS-Security?

Comment: Yes, the ticket needs to go in the header. Maybe my only option is to not use an send port and implement a C# class which handles the communication and run this from the orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is not you, your app or BizTalk Server.  It's the other service using Xml, then not following the Xml rules.  Unfortunately, they've made it your, and every other client's, problem to solve.

Don't write a custom c# class to handle this communication, that's just creating more problems.

First, try a **custom WCF Behavior or Message Inspector** that injects the token to the header.